# Show icecast metadata (title) in WordPress using PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, php-curl, icecast, shoutcast

I want to display the song's title, from an icecast 2.4.0 stream, in my WordPress page using php (with php_everywhere)

The title is avaiable in /admin/stats.xml, but it's protected by basic auth and I can't modify the status-json.xsl for some reasons ( I'm not the admin of the icecast server ), so I have to take metadata from the /admin/stats.xml for which I have the username and password.

I tried to make a basic auth using curl, or with the syntax  http://user:pass@host:port/...., but it doesn't work, the server doesn't respond to my request with the xml page.

I tried some libraries, that I found on the web, that provide an IceCast class in php, but my wordpress page makes an 403 error in this case.
For example: [PHP - Icecast info being updated on page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31157493/php-icecast-info-being-updated-on-page)

Answer (score 1):

Please upgrade to the latest Icecast version (2.4.4 at this time), as it has important security and stability fixes. If your Linux distribution doesn't have it, you can install official Xiph.org packages: https://wiki.xiph.org/Icecast_Server/Installing_latest_version_(official_Xiph_repositories)

Importantly it also offers a JSON API endpoint to access metadata at /status-json.xsl (importantly this is broken in 2.4.0). This does not require authentication.